# Can I blow dryer exhaust into a pillow case or sheet?

Tags: dryer, exhaust-vent

Go ahead and laugh.  It's okay.  Before you do, though, hear me out.

My dryer has been drying less and less lately.  Today, it stopped drying.  Now I have a full load of wet laundry and it's all the clothes I got.  I just tried cleaning my exhaust duct/vent/whatever with one of those things with the bristles and the coily "handle", but I have had no luck.  I tried cleaning it from inside the house and outside, but nothing.  The dryer is blowing out exhaust out the back, though, so I know it's doing it's share of the work.  However, even with the exhaust hose hooked up, I feel absolutely no air blowing out of the vent outside.  I've peered down its full length with an LED flashlight from the outside and even stuck my cell phone up in it and snapped a clear pic from the inside and I see no blockages.  I've even felt along the length of the exhaust hose while the dryer was going and felt no air escaping through tears or around the gaskets that hold it to the wall and the back of the dryer.

I am just going to call someone to come and do it, but, being the week of Thanksgiving and all, I doubt I'll be able to get anyone here until next week.  Meanwhile, I have a load of laundry that needs to be dried.  Therefore, I've come up with the temporary -- and idiotic -- idea to attach a pillow case to the end and let it rip.  However, the idea of dying in a fire just days before the delicious Thanksgiving feast leaves me sort of questioning whether or not I should do this.  Had I a longer hose, I'd just stick it out the garage door and let it rip.  However, I don't, so I won't.

What do I do about this mess?  Somebody help me.

Comment: Fire you can escape.  If it is a gas dryer, then you could die of CO poisoning, and that you usually don't escape until it is too late.

Comment: @Gunner It's electric.  Anyway, I went ahead and did it and am doing it right now.  I've been keeping an eye on the pillow case and it's warm, but nowhere near as hot as the inside of the dryer itself.  I took a pic for lols.  Maybe I'll post it so everyone here can have lols, too.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin - post the pic - post the pic - post the pic; we just have to see that inflated pillow case!

Comment: Is is now drying your clothes? If it's not close to as hot as inside the dryer, do you think it could be a blockage inside the dryer itself?

Comment: Folks used a device called a [clothes line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clothes_line) for many years to successfully dry clothes.

Comment: I'm confused as to the purpose of the pillow case. Why not just run the dryer with no exhaust piping connected at all? If it's an electric dryer, it probably won't kill you to run it that way once. I just wouldn't make a habit of running it vent free.

Comment: @Tester101 The pillow case is to serve as a filter to keep lint from blowing all over my kitchen.  The air can pass through the fabric, but the lint can't, sort of like a vacuum cleaner bag (I think).  It actually worked rather well and I was able to dry a full load of laundry without my chestnuts roasting on an open fire.

Comment: @getterdun There's air coming out of the exhaust in the back.  I finally realized there was a blockage in the exhaust pipe itself when I opened my dryer and steam came billowing out.

Comment: You'd be better off if you put the exhaust into a bucket full of water.

Comment: @Edwin Damn, I wish I thought of that.  I'd have put some dishsoap in it and turned it into a bubble-making machine!

Comment: Sorry this so late and why is it not obvious to you that if you dryer has been drying less and less and now stopped drying, it's suffering from a blockage.

Either your manual will explain how to remedy that, or you need to call an expert technician.

Any other choice might burn down your house and kill your family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I am answering my own question here.  The answer is "Yes, you can!" (or at least "Yes, I did!").

I am sure it's safe so long as you keep an eye on it.  The pillow case didn't get absurdly hot, either.  After about 40 minutes, my load was done.  Now that I got my vent cleaned today, I should see even faster drying times since the pillow case method wasn't without its share of airflow resistance.

The first pic is of my pillow case experiment.  No laughing at the outdated laminate floor as that was there when I bought the place (so I guess you can still laugh at me a little).  Also, no laughing at the outdated 90's pillowcase design.  Do mind the mess.

The second pic is what they pulled out of my vent today.  No wonder there was no airflow!

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is why code calls for rigid smooth walled dryer exhaust ducting.  That foil flex junk is not supposed to be used for dryer exhaust, it's for things like bathroom exhaust fans.  Replace that ducting ASAP.

Comment: @Tester101 Ah, good call.  I will replace it myself very soon.

Comment: @Tester101 thank, I had not given this a thought. My dryer is in the basement and vents into the driveway with a simple plastic piece that goes through a basement window. So it is easy to work with. Anyway, the snowblower has demolished the exterior vent. I was going to replace that, and after your comment, I think I will use rigid venting for at least everything up until the last tiny bit that hooks up to the dryer itself.

Comment: @JohnGaughan They sell semi-rigid duct (as described in [this question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/29572/33)), that can be used to connect the dryer to the rigid ducting.  Personally, I stick to the shortest piece possible (2 ft.), but code wise I think you can use an 8 ft. piece.

Answer (score 4):

I'm presuming you're using the pillow case as a lint filter.  The bigger problem will be humidity.  You'll be putting all of the moisture from the wet clothes into the air.  After a couple loads, this makes the room really, really, REALLY humid (I've been there).

If you can swing it, you might be well off getting some flex dryer duct and running the end out the window while you're doing laundry.  Then you won't need the pillowcase at all, which might cause some other problems due to back pressure/poor airflow (e.g., it might take longer for your clothes to dry, and it might cause the dryer to run hotter).

Answer (score 1):

In the winter, I disconnect my (electric) dryer exhaust hose, plug the hole in the wall and put a knee high panty hose on the end. Very easy to clean  the lintel out of. Why waste heat and no more bloody noses from the dry winter air.

Comment: Just keep an eye on the amount of humidity you're introducing this way -- houses do not like excess humidity much, either!